# Python map Numpy array Into Class with OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

How do I map a Numpy Array into a class with certain members?

```
perimeterValues = cv2.arcLength(curveData, True)
vertices = cv2.approxPolyDP(curveData, 0.04 * perimeterValues, True)

Results: [[[[257, 396]], [[225, 397]], [[210, 431]], [[235, 450]], [[265, 435]]]]
```

It needs to go into a List class with discrete class members as follows:

```
verticesList : list[Vertices] 

class Vertices():
  xLocation: int
  yLocation: int
```

in previous attempt, I would lose the name of class members xLocation, yLocation, etc

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: As it stands, you have a retirement, and are just asking for someone to write your code instead of presenting a programming problem that you ran into.

Comment: yeah there is no effort here

Comment: I'm not sure how to parse the numpy array, and trying to find resource, couldn't locate anything in documentation @MadPhysicist

Comment: You couldn't run a simple `for` loop?

Comment: in the for loop, how do I parse the first one with element ref?  257? not sure about parsing numpy arrays, etc [[257, 396]],

Comment: it is an array - you use coordinates, how bout you read some documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html